# How to show a progress dialog without message (I only need the indeterminate circle)?

Tags: android, loading, progressdialog

How can I show a progress dialog without the message?

I only need to show the indeterminate circle. What is the easiest and fastest way of doing this without creating a custom dialog? Is there any method similar to this:

`progressDialog.setShowIndeterminateCircleOnly(true)`

Comment: ProgressBar should suffice your requirement !

Comment: Well, I can't do anything if that's not what the client wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need a only spinning wheel without box, you can use like this.

```
<ProgressBar
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/progressbar_downloading"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

Comment: Set reference to XML file for your Dialog like...
progressDialog.setContentView( R.layout.progress_bar ); 

This solution still DOES show the box covering parent width.

Comment: Why this answer is accepted as right one? when question is about only to show progress circle with progress dialog(Not with progress bar).

Answer (score 11):

Hope this will help some as answer is still not easily found.

```
ProgressDialog progDialog = ProgressDialog.show( getContext(), null, null, false, true );
progDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT ) );
progDialog.setContentView( R.layout.progress_bar );
```

2nd line above will remove the box around the progress Circle icon; but it will stay left aligned by default. You will have to add the third line above to handle gravity and any other style in a XML layout file.

progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

You do not have to define the style above if you like the default smaller circle Icon

Answer (score -1):

Do only progressbar in your xml file

```
    <ProgressBar 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

or Create ProgressDialog without setting title

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this, "", "", true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: If I do that, there will be an extra space on the right of the circle. The box will still be a rectangle. I want the box to cover only the circle.

Comment: You need to do a custom view for your dialog. The SDK dev guide has examples

Comment: Thank you, it seems I have no choice but to create a custom dialog.

Comment: if u want only moving circle in progress dialog then only way to do custom dialog from xml file and inflate through layoutinflater in java class.u can also set a animated gif image in progressdialog. Thanks

Comment: @android_dev: I tried creating a custom dialog having only the circle but the width of the dialog does not change. How do I make the width smaller?